# How do I only display data if query string is in the URL codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to only display data if the url has a query string.
In example
I want the data displayed at http://example.com/users only to me accessible by the correct query string

http://example.com/users?access-token=b393c6

This is my controller:

```
public function users() {
        $users = $this->cd_model->selectAllusers();
        $users_json = json_encode($users, true);
        echo $users_json;
        $this->load_view('/users');

}
```

and this is my model

```
public function selectAllusers() {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: You need to check **$_GET['access_token'**] if is set and match your condition, then dispaly users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller just check either there is any query string parameters or not it could be through GET method or POST. If only Get required then use $this->input->get(null); instead of $this->input->get_post(null);

```
public function users() {
        $queryString = $this->input->get_post(null);
        if($queryString && !empty($queryString['access-token'])){
         $users = $this->cd_model->selectAllusers();
         $users_json = json_encode($users, true);
         echo $users_json;
        }
        $this->load_view('/users');

}
```

Comment: Is it `access_token` or `access-token`? ... because you're using the former and the OP is using the latter.